# Sleeping threads in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, wait

I am currently working on a project where I am to have essentially 10 threads that are "sleeping". At random one of these 10 threads is to "wake up" and start doing some work. I just want to see if I am headed in the right direction. So should I just create each instance of the thread for instance.

```
Thread thread0 = new Thread(new doWork());
...
Thread thread9 = new Thread(new doWork());
```

and just not start them and then when they are to "wake" just call the `start()` method on the particular thread..

or should I start each thread but have them `wait()` until I call the `notify()` method?

or should I start the thread and use `sleep()` and then call the `interrupt()` method?

Which approach seems to be better and why?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

**edit** Will this be acceptable??

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Client {

private static Thread [] clients = new Thread[10];

public static void main(String[] args){

    createClients();
    randomWake();

}// end main()

static void createClients(){

    Thread client0 = new Thread(new ClientThread(0));
    clients[0] = client0;
    Thread client1 = new Thread(new ClientThread(1));
    clients[1] = client1;
    Thread client2 = new Thread(new ClientThread(2));
    clients[2] = client2;
    Thread client3 = new Thread(new ClientThread(3));
    clients[3] = client3;
    Thread client4 = new Thread(new ClientThread(4));
    clients[4] = client4;
    Thread client5 = new Thread(new ClientThread(5));
    clients[5] = client5;
    Thread client6 = new Thread(new ClientThread(6));
    clients[6] = client6;
    Thread client7 = new Thread(new ClientThread(7));
    clients[7] = client7;
    Thread client8 = new Thread(new ClientThread(8));
    clients[8] = client8;
    Thread client9 = new Thread(new ClientThread(9));
    clients[9] = client9;

    for(int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++)
        clients[i].start();

}// end createClients()

static void randomWake(){

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(10);

    clients[randomNumber].interrupt();

}// end randomWake()

static class ClientThread implements Runnable{

    private int clientNumber;

    public ClientThread(int clientNumber){
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
    }// end ClientThread(int clientNumber)

    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.interrupted()){}
        System.out.println("Client " + clientNumber + " is awake!");
    }// end run()

}// end class ClientThread
```

}// end class Client

Comment: How about  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); ?

Comment: @cho: That's in the case an event might occur. Hower the question states that the threads are activated "randomly"...

Answer (score 0):

**In case there is a maximum amount of sleep time**

You probably will need to implement the following `Thread` class:

```
public class DoWork extends Thread {

    public void run () {
        while(true) {
            Thread.Sleep((int) Math.floor(Math.random()*10000));
            //do some work
        }
    }

}
```

Where `10000` is the maximum time in milliseconds a thread should sleep.

**In case there is no maximum amount of sleep time**

You probably will need to implement the following `Thread` class:

```
public class DoWork extends Thread {

    public void run () {
        while(true) {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            if(Math.random() < 0.005d) {
            //do some work
            }
        }
    }

}
```

where `0.005` is the probability of running the method a certain millisecond.

---

`notify` and `wait` are used to implement *Semaphores*: this are objects that prevent two threads to manipulate the same object at the same time (since some objects could end up in an illegal state).

Comment: Well I added a case where there is no maximum amount of sleep time.

Comment: well the way I have been doing threads for this particular class and all projects before hand I use `implements Runnable` .. so should I be using `extends Threads` to make them sleep correctly?

Comment: No, `Thread.Sleep` is a static method. You can even call it without using any threads/multiprogramming. It is quite confusing it is implemented there anyway.

Comment: Okay so basically the code you've provided will make every thread I create `sleep` upon start, how would I go about "waking" them up when I want them to perform a task? Will I be able to use `thread0.interrupt()` to make the thread stop sleeping?

Comment: no, according to your question, the threads should wake at random moments. In case of event triggered tasks, you should use a *ThreadPool*.

Comment: You don't "wake up" a thread on demand.  A thread can put itself to sleep using the ubiquitous Thread.sleep() method mentioned above.  There is no guarantee of how long it will sleep or when and in what order sleeping threads wake up.  It simply allows the OS to start working on another thread.  Threads will already randomly be executed by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

How about using semaphores?

```
class DoWork extends Runnable {
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    DoWork(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            semaphore.acquire();
            //do some work
        }
    }
}
```

The main program can create an array of Semaphores, and an equal number of Threads running DoWork instances, so that each DoWork instance has its own semaphore.  Each time the main program calls sema[i].release(), The run() method of the corresponding DoWork instance will "do some work" and then go back to waiting.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense your answer, so not sure what you really want to achieve. But for what you describe you should put all threads waiting on the same lock and just notify the lock (it will awake only one randomly)

But as that doesn't make much sense, I guess you want to achieve something different.

Check this question regarding sleep vs wait: [Difference between wait() and sleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036754/difference-between-wait-and-sleep)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one. This is how I would solve it if I were not to use ThreadPooling (which is  very correct as the others have said) and so that I can see how `wait()`,`notify()` and `Thread.sleep()` work. Checking google you will see (e.g. [Thread.sleep and object.wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693361/thread-sleep-and-object-wait)) that the mainly `wait()` and `notify()` are used for communication between threads and `Thread.sleep` is used so that you can pause your program.

-Part of this answer is based on this: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-signaling.html#missedsignals. You can check in the code to see the steps that you need to take (comment out some parts of the code) in order to make your program hang, so that you realize how to work with missed signals. The iterations needed for your program to hang are not fixed.

-The programm will run forever. You will need to work on it a bit in order to fix that.

**Main**

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Manager mgr = new Manager("manager");
        mgr.start();
    }
}
```

**Manager**

```
public class Manager extends Thread
{
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private boolean wasSignalled = false;

    private DoWork[] workThreads = new DoWork[5];

    public Manager(String name){
        super(name);

        workThreads[0] = new DoWork(this,"work 0");
        workThreads[1] = new DoWork(this,"work 1");
        workThreads[2] = new DoWork(this,"work 2");
        workThreads[3] = new DoWork(this,"work 3");
        workThreads[4] = new DoWork(this,"work 4");
    }


    public void wakeUP()
    {
        synchronized (this.lock) {
            wasSignalled = true;
            this.lock.notify();
         }
    }
    public void pauseAndWait()
    {
        synchronized (this.lock) {
            if(!wasSignalled)
            {
                try {
                    this.lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //clear signal and continue running.
            wasSignalled = false;
         }
    }

    public void run () 
    {
        int i=0;
        while(true)
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println(" manager ...: "+i+" ");

            int choose = 0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((4 - 0) + 1));
            //choose=0; for debugginng

            if(!workThreads[choose].isAlive()){
                workThreads[choose].start();
            }
            else{
                workThreads[choose].wakeUP();
            }

            //wait to be notified by DoWork thread when its job
            //is done
            pauseAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

**DoWork**

```
public class DoWork extends Thread
{
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private boolean wasSignalled = false;

    private Manager managerThread;

    public DoWork(Manager managerThread,String name){
        super(name);

        this.managerThread=managerThread;
    }


    public void wakeUP()
    {
        synchronized (this.lock) {

            //check what happens without wasSignalled flag 
            //step #1: comment out wasSignalled = true;
            wasSignalled = true;    
            this.lock.notify();
         }
    }
    public void pauseAndWait()
    {
        synchronized (this.lock) {
            //check what happens without wasSignalled flag 
            //step #2: comment out the if block
            if(!wasSignalled)
            {
                try {
                    this.lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            //check what happens without wasSignalled flag 
            //step #3: comment out wasSignalled = false;

            //clear signal and continue running.
            wasSignalled = false;
         }
    }

    public void run () 
    {
        int i=0;
        while(true) 
        {           
            i++;

            try {
                System.out.print(this.getName()+" going to sleep ...: "+i+" ");

                //check what happens without wasSignalled flag 
                //step #4: put sleep time to Thread.sleep(0); 

                //simulate worker thread job
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
                System.out.println(" woke up ... ");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println(" worker thread: job simulation error:"+e);
            }

            //if worker thread job simulation is done (sleep for 4 times)
            //then suspend thread and wait to be awaken again
            if(i>4)
            {
                System.out.println(this.getName()+" notifying main  ...: "+i+" \n");
                i=0;
                managerThread.wakeUP();

                // thread does not get destroyed, it stays in memory and when the manager
                // thread calls it again it will wake up do its job again
                pauseAndWait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```